# Group and join give missing field

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, join

I'm doing LINQ to SQL, and when I add a group clause, it complains that my joining field does not exist.  What am I missing?
I have:

```
var q = from f in db.Faults
        group f by f.FaultID into groupF
        join af in db.AvailabilityFaults on groupF.FaultID equals af.FaultID
        select groupF;
```

The problem is that it complains that 'groupF.FaultID' does not exist.  If I remove the Group clause, then it works if I change the prefix alias (f.FaultID).

Comment: @abatishchev ... LINQ to linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on the Group `Key` like so:

```
var q = from f in db.Faults
        group f by f.FaultID into groupF
        join af in db.AvailabilityFaults on groupF.Key equals af.FaultID
        select groupF
```

The `Key` value will be the `FaultID` for that group, so it should work as expected.